# get different pages from different slugs

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have my logic like this but I can't implement it on my wordpress I'm new to this platform.

- get different pages from different slugs
- display a page title and a content from slug1
- display a page title and a content from slug2
- display a page title and a content from slug3

all in all they will be display on a single page.

Comment: as you mentioned you are new to this platform, did you get your terminology correct ? do you mean `"pages"` or did you wanted to say `"posts"` ??

Comment: hmmmn.. these are pages and will display into a single page..

to get these pages.. I consider their slugs to be the key. maybe I'll declare the slugs first.. how'll do that on wordpress?

Comment: slugs are usually being made automatically from the title , based on how you structure your [permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to get the pages from the ID rather than the pages, even though they're called "permalinks" you can still change them and then you'll have to update your code as well, which is a pain of course.

I'd advise you to create a template for you page, when you've done that you can query multiple posts/pages in the template.

You can create a template like this:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Snarfer
*/
?>
```

After that you can query the different posts like this:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'page_id=7' ); //this will get the page with teh ID 7

while ( $query -> have_posts() ) : $query -> the_post();
    //query the page data here like the_content(), the_title();
endwhile;
```

If you want the same styling for all your queried pages then you'd be better of querying with the `post__in` variable. Read more about the different options here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters

Read more about custom templates here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I am not using the correct approach. I did just right by displaying the 3 posts given by their IDs

```
<?php
    $postslist  = get_posts('include=120,122,124&orderby=ID&order=ASC');
                    foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>

     <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

                  <?php endforeach; ?>
```